# How to make golang's Logrus share the same config through several files?

Tags: go

The plain demo code works as they integrated the Logrus's config and the logic of `main`, as follows

```
func main() {
    var filename string = "logfile.log"
    f, err := os.OpenFile(filename, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE, 0644)
    Formatter := new(log.TextFormatter)
    Formatter.TimestampFormat = "02-01-2006 15:04:05"
    Formatter.FullTimestamp = true
    log.SetFormatter(Formatter)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        log.SetOutput(f)
    }

    log.Info("Some info. Earth is not flat")
    log.Warning("This is a warning")
    log.Error("Not fatal. An error. Won't stop execution")
}
```

But in real world, the config of logrus should be seperated into individual file, consider the file structure as :

```
logrusdemo/
├── main.go
└── mylib
    ├── aa.go
    └── bb.go
```

And I want to share the same config in these files:

The source code of `aa.go`:

```
package mylib

// GetTestA testing
func GetTestA() string {
    //log.info("entering aa.go")
    return "001"
}
```

The source code of `bb.go`:

```
package mylib

// GetTestB testing
func GetTestB() string {
    //log.info("entering bb.go")
    return "001"
}
```

The source code of `main.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "logrusdemo/mylib"
)

func main() {
    //log.info("entering main")
    fmt.Printf("%v", mylib.GetTestA())
    fmt.Printf("%v", mylib.GetTestB())
}
```

I was wondering how to make logrus works in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by passing your logger to your structs / functions.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
    "logrusdemo/mylib"
)

func main() {
    log = logrus.New()

    var filename string = "logfile.log"
    f, err := os.OpenFile(filename, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE, 0644)

    Formatter := new(log.TextFormatter)
    Formatter.TimestampFormat = "02-01-2006 15:04:05"
    Formatter.FullTimestamp = true
    log.SetFormatter(Formatter)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        log.SetOutput(f)
    }

    log.Info("Some info. Earth is not flat")
    log.Warning("This is a warning")
    log.Error("Not fatal. An error. Won't stop execution")

    fmt.Printf("%v", mylib.GetTestA(log))
    fmt.Printf("%v", mylib.GetTestB(log))
}
```

And

```
package mylib

import (
    "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

// GetTestA testing
func GetTestA(log *logrus.Logger) string {
    log.Info("entering aa.go")
    return "001"
}
```

If you don't want to pass it as an argument, you can also pass your logger in a context, or use it as a global.

Comment: Thanks, any detail to use it as global config?

Comment: @pvd: Don't use global config. Use dependency injection as described in this answer.

Comment: @Flimzy Why not global config? If it's a large project with more than 1000 functions, we would not to want every function has a parameter to pass the log handler.

Comment: 1. Because globals are dangerous. 2. Passing an argument isn't the only way to do dependency injection. Make your config part of a struct, and call methods on that struct instead.

Comment: @Flimzy Any example or tutorial link? I just google and find that other guys doesn't support the context solution. https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/5ovkut/sharing_loggers_across_contexts_and_packages/dcmkxj3/ ,

Comment: I think adding a solution like https://github.com/practo/k8s-worker-pod-autoscaler/blob/master/cmd/workerpodautoscaler/main.go#L31 could be more helpful, passing to all functions will make the code very bad.